what does two by two disjoint mean?
I am faced with this definition but dont know what it means and on the internet I did not find a short explanation. I know this question is rather basic but I could not think of another forum to ask in.
Thanks!
Consider the space $U = [0,1]^d$
for some
fixed d. The decomposition tree T(U) of U is an infinite binary tree, whose
root represents U. In general, every node $v$ in the tree represents a subcube $U'$
in $U$, and the children of $v$ represent two subcubes $U''$
and $U'''$
where $U''$
and $U'''$ are the result of cutting $U'$
in the middle at the smallest dimension in which
$U'$ has a maximum side length. The subcubes $U''$
and $U'''$ are closed, i.e., their
intersection defines the cut.
now the mention of two-by-two disjoint:
3 conditions:
1 The interiors of the subcubes associated with the (nodes assigned to the)
peers are two-by-two disjoint.
peers are peers in a P2P system and they just correspond 1-1 to a node within the tree.

Where are you encountering this term?  A citation would be helpful.

Wonder if he means "pairwise disjoint". A collection $\mathscr{C}$ of sets is "pairwise disjoint" if $X\cap Y = \varnothing$ for every distinct $X,Y\in\mathscr{C}$.

thanks all, I added the definition in question and some more information hope it is sufficient.

Looks like a translation. In Spanish you might say "disjuntos dos a dos", which would be rendered literally as "disjoint two by two." It just means pairwise disjoint, as others have said. If you have a family ${X_i}{i\in I}$, then asking for  "pairwise disjoint" means that $X_i\cap X_j=\varnothing$ whenever $i\neq j$; this is stronger than asking for $\cap{i\in I}X_i = \varnothing$.
